# How to upload a blob form in Javascript to Django backend

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have an audio blob with the following code I'm looking to send to a form with javascript

```
function sendData(blob) {
  let fd = new FormData;
  fd.append('fname', 'test.wav');
  fd.append("recording", blob);
  let token = '{{csrf_token}}';

  $.ajax({
    url: 'landing/submit/',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': token },
    data: fd,
    cache: false,
    processData: false, // essential
    contentType: false, // essential, application/pdf doesn't work.
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  });
}
```

I am trying to send this to a django form, but i'm getting a 403 error. Here is the view it's being sent to:

```
views.py

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostAudio(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            return redirect('landing-home')
    else:
        form = PostAudio()
    return render(request, 'landing/submit.html', {'form': form})
```

What am I missing? Most other folks posting online say this has to do with not using CSRF tokens, but I included them in my headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the @csrf_token decorator in django . I had a  similar problem that solved it.

try this

```
@csrf_exempt
def post_new(request):
```

Comment: got it. where would I put the token decorator?